# Breaker keeps tripping

Tags: electrical-panel

Replaced a split circuit switch (Dishwasher/Disposal). breaker comes on when switched but trips when turning either appliance on. Tab is removed, all wires connected properly, but breaker still trips

Comment: Is this breaker an AFCI or GFCI?

Comment: The breaker is GFCI.

Comment: Are the dishwasher and disposal on the same circuit, or on two different circuits?

Comment: They are on different circuits.

Comment: Was the previous breaker GFCI?  When you say "different circuits" do you mean different supply wires from this same breaker? Can either appliance be unplugged or are they hardwired?

Comment: The receptacle was replaced.  The breaker was not.  Both appliances can be unplugged.  The appliances are not plugged up to the receptacle.

Comment: Do those circuits (really, one *multi-wire branch circuit*) serve any other outlets or wired loads? Is it possible the bare ground wire or the side of the box could be touching a hot or neutral screw terminal?  One type of ground fault is a neutral-ground fault, and GFCIs check for that.

Comment: The circuits do not serve other loads - one for the dishwasher, the other for the disposal.  There are no wires touching each other or the box or a screw besides the intended screw connector.

Comment: Any chance of a cable pinch somewhere in the route?  I would unhook it at the breaker and measure with an ohmmeter from hot1-ground, hot2-ground, and neutral-ground.  Should all be infinity.   A better test would be a megger, but even I don't own one of those.

Comment: Circuits...two(2) seperate breakers? or just 2 seperate line cables? If it is 1 breaker, you have 1 circuit. One suggestion was unplug them, when you do, plug just the disposal in and try it If it still trips, you have a ground fault in the box or the wires from the breaker to the box. Is this a switch or outlets tht we are talking about?